# Notation for $ \mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z}$, integers mod $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How come people write the integers mod $n$, i.e. the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z} \equiv \mathbb{Z}_n$ as

$\mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z} \equiv \mathbb{Z}_n = \{0,1,2,...n-1\}$?

Isn't this incorrect? Should it not be $\mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z} \equiv \mathbb{Z}_n = \{[0],[1],...,[n-1]\}$ where $[a]= a + n\mathbb{Z} = \{b \in \mathbb{Z}: b \equiv a$ mod $n \}$ are the cosets. I am quite confused about this. Clearly the elements are not the same.

Comment: To say that $\mathbb{Z}_n = \{[0],[1],\dots,[n-1]\}$ is correct. The reason why we do otherwise is just out of laziness. It's annoying to write brackets all the time, when we can just have the mutual understanding that we are talking about the classes.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you.  Something like $\mathbb{Z}_n = \{1,2,...,n-1\}$ mod $n$  or $\mathbb{Z}_n = \{1,2,...,n-1\}_n$ would have been clearer.

Comment: Congruence classes mod $n$ are the exact same thing as cosets of the subgroup $\langle n \rangle$.  People are lazy with the brackets, which is acceptable.

Comment: Technically, you *can* define a group structure on the *set* $\{0,1,2.\ldots,n-1\}$, with addition defined by setting $a+_n b$ to be $a+b$ if $a+b\leq n-1$, and $a+_n b = a+b-n$ otherwise. There is no magic required set to give the group, so long as the operation is defined or clear from context. In this case, the resulting objects are all isomorphic, so it doesn’t matter much in the end. I will note that many people object to the notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$: number theorists don’t like it because they use $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for the $p$_adics; and others because they reserve it for the quotient ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, saying "$\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z=\{0,1,...,n-1\}$" is not formally correct but more of an abuse of notation.

Something that can be done to somehow justify this, is defining a system of presentatives for the quotient group as follows:

Let $X\subset G$ we say $X$ is a system of representatives of $G/H$ if:$$|X\cap gH|=1 ,\forall g\in G$$ Having defined that, one can see the map: $$X \longrightarrow G/H \\ x \mapsto xH$$ is a bijection from the system of representatives to the quotient subgroup. So in your particular example saying "$\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z=\{0,1,...,n-1\}$" is a way of saying the set $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ is a set of representatives of $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$.

I hope this helps.